# Draw on canvas: mouseover and mouseclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I added a snippet to make it easier to understand.

This snippet only draws on mouse over, but I'd liked it to draw only when you click and move on the same time.

I tried to get this action with this code below, but it doesn't work.

```
$(document).on('mouseover click','#canvas', function(event){
    if(event.type == "mouseover" && event.type == "click"){
       alert("e");
    }
});
```

//BEGIN SNIPPET

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

$("#canvas").mousemove(function(arg) {
 context.fillStyle = "#1477CC";
    var pos = getMousePos(canvas, arg);
    context.beginPath();
 context.arc(pos.x+50,pos.y,5,0,2*Math.PI);
 context.fill();
});

function getMousePos(canvas, e) {
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();  
    return {
        x: e.clientX - rect.left,              
        y: e.clientY - rect.top
    };
}

//Clear

$("#clear").click(function() {
    var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
 var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
 ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
 ctx.fillRect(0,0,380,300);
});
```

```css
#canvas{
border: 1px solid black;
}

#clear:hover{
cursor: pointer;
 text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<canvas id="canvas">
  
</canvas>

<div onclick="clear();" id="clear">
    Clear
</div>
```

Comment: You need to register the state: when the user clicks save the "enable" state for the pencil, while on `mouseup` just clear that state. When moving check the current state and let it draw when it's in the right one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested you could add a flag to enable drawing:

```
var enableDraw = false;

$("#canvas").mousedown(function(arg) {
    enableDraw = true;
});

$("#canvas").mouseup(function(arg) {
    enableDraw = false;
});

$("#canvas").mousemove(function(arg) {
    if(enableDraw){
        context.fillStyle = "#1477CC";
        var pos = getMousePos(canvas, arg);
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(pos.x+50,pos.y,5,0,2*Math.PI);
        context.fill();
    }
});
```

### [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/udt9ae02/)

Comment: Thanks, just did the same

Comment: By the way, do you know why this position isn't precise? Can't find anything better on the web

Comment: why do you add `+50` on `x` when you draw ? without it it's correct. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/udt9ae02/1/). For drawing on canvas you could test this tiny library [sketch.js](http://intridea.github.io/sketch.js/)

Comment: It's because my canvas is on position absolute +50. Thank you for the library

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

Thanks to MarcoCl

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var draw = false;

$(document).on('mouseup mousedown','#canvas', function(event){
    if(event.type == "mousedown"){
       draw = true;
    }
    if(event.type == "mouseup"){
       draw = false;
    }
});



$("#canvas").mousemove(function(arg) {
    if(draw){
      context.fillStyle = "#1477CC";
      var pos = getMousePos(canvas, arg);
      context.beginPath();
   context.arc(pos.x+50,pos.y,5,0,2*Math.PI);
   context.fill(); 
     }
});

function getMousePos(canvas, e) {
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();  
    return {
        x: e.clientX - rect.left,              
        y: e.clientY - rect.top
    };
}

//Clear

$("#clear").click(function() {
    var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
 var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
 ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
 ctx.fillRect(0,0,380,300);
});
```

```css
#canvas{
border: 1px solid black;
}

#clear:hover{
cursor: pointer;
 text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<canvas id="canvas">
  
</canvas>

<div onclick="clear();" id="clear">
    Clear
</div>
```